# Windows Storage server 2003 file permissions issue

Tags: windows-storage-server, permissions

We have our users set up so that their My Documents folders are targeting individual network folders on a Windows 2003 Storage server.  I am having an issue where a user who has Windows XP professional cannot open,or delete any of the folders she creates, I am not able to open or delete them either even under the domain administrator account.  It will not let me take over permissions or even open the folders.  She is logging on through the domain.

Comment: Have you gone under the Owner tab and taken ownership with the Domain Administrator account?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder and go to the security tab. Click advanced, and go to the ownership tab. This'll allow you to change the owner of the file. Once you're the owner, you will be able to restore the correct NTFS permissions.

[image]

Comment: Yes it won't allow me, it says access denied

Comment: From an Elevated command prompt try: Takeown /a /r /d Y /f <directory to folder>